# how to implement google map api on ios5.1 and ios6 upper both?

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios6, sdk, ios5.1

I have a question.

I need to implement Google Maps API on iOS5.1 and iOS6.

I know google map have bulid in ios 5.1. But the Google Map API become third part if you need to use.

I need to implement google maps api on iOS5.1 and iOS6.

I reference the Google Map SDK API Tutorial.

The tutorial point to Supported Platforms is iOS SDK 6.0 or later.

I implemented Google Maps API on iOS6 is correct show the maps.( use iPhone 6.0 Simulator)

I am use ios Deployment Target 5.1.

But If I change to iPhone 5.1 Simulator.

The application had crashed.

I checked the crash problem reason is "Other Linker Flags set -ObjC" cause.

But I need to implement the Google Maps on iOS 5.1 and iOS6 .

How to resolve this problem, please?

How to write the google maps api on ios5.1 and ios6 both?

thank you very much.

I attach to the log on distributed on iOS 5.1 version :

```
    yld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIActivityViewController
    Referenced from: /Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/EC6760CC-D272-4949-A5BA-6AFB8B0C1A8F/HM.app/HM
    Expected in:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDK s/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
    in /Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/EC6760CC-D272-4949-A5BA-6AFB8B0C1A8F/HM.app/HM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Google Maps SDK for iOS release notes:

"Version 1.5.0 requires iOS 6.0 or later. Applications that must support iOS 5.1 should continue to use the most recent 1.4.x release."

You'll just have to use the older version of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was not use UIActivityViewController. The problem was show after I add Google Maps API. But I had write google maps for ios6 code before I checked ios version. 
The iOS 6 google maps sdk tutorial point to add "-ObjC" in project. If I delete the "-Objec" , maps SDK code (ios6 version ) and ran the ios5.1 simulator. The application was not crashed. But if I remove the "-Objc" , the iOS6 code was can't use. @@ thank you ~

Comment: Thank you very much~ I am switch to version 1.4.3. The problem is resolve. Thank you~ :)  You are a enthusiastic man. The world need like you kind person more. :)

Comment: API 1.4.x don't load map in iOS 7 for me, I must upgrade to 1.6.x